# How do I make a custom marker for my plot legends?

Tags: plotting, legending

I have written the code to make some plots and now I want to add legends to them. I want to have the type of legends shown in the picture below; i.e., two lines corresponding to each parameter

[image: I want to write this type of legends, i.e two lines corresponding to one parameter]

Kindly help me.

Comment: Share your complete try...

Answer (score 2):

Use [`PointLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PointLegend.html) with a custom marker. Like so:

```
marker = 
  Graphics[{Line[{{0., .25}, {2., .25}}], Dashed, Line[{{0., -.25}, {2., -.25}}]}]
PointLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"label1", "label2", "label3"},
  LegendMarkers -> {marker, marker, marker}]
```

[image: legend]